# I can't run a program on Blue J

Tags: java, macos, bluej

My programs on Blue J compile correctly and when I want to run it, the "run button" is gone. It is replaced with these buttons:

-new A2_1()

-void main(String[] args)

-Open Editor          .......(letters in red color)

-Compile          .............(letters in red color)

-Inspect              ..............(letters in red color)

-Remove          .............(letters in red color)

************ It does that to all programs I am trying to run.********

A2_1 is just the class name of the program. I will say again: I can compile it but CANNOT RUN IT. I have no further technical experience with BlueJ to fix this problem.

If it helps:

-I have the current JDK. 
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

-I have OS X 10.9.5

This problem came after I changed something in my Mac. I was taking a programming class at the time and we were studying inheritance. And I needed programs to access other previous written programs in order to run. Upon request of the professor I changed something in my Mac that deals with folder locations. That is all I remember.

Comment: The [current JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html) is 1.8.0_31, although that isn't the cause of your trouble.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

After you compiled the class:

1. Right click on the class (on its icon)
2. Click on `void main(String args[])`
3. Click on <kbd>Ok</kbd> (because probably you don't need arguments for the `main` method)